# ClassNotFoundException while running a jar though it contails all tha classes

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, jar, mapreduce

I have created a `jar` using `eclipse` for the `mapreduce` jobs. If you extract the `jar` you can see all the class present there. When you `run` the `jar` in ``` hadoop``using ```hadoop` command it shows error shown below.

Its not able to recognize only one class i.e `Test_project$TwoDArrayWritables`. `Test_project` is the `main` class and `TwoDArrayWritables` is a `class` within `Test_project`. `TwoDArrayWritables` inherit `TwoDArrayWritable` built-in class in `hadoop`.

Jar extract Image:

[image]

**Error:**

```
16/04/05 15:48:28 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201604051120_0002_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mapreduce.Test_project$TwoDArrayWritables
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getMapOutputValueClass(JobConf.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.<init>(MapTask.java:966)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mapreduce.Test_project$TwoDArrayWritables
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:857)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:881)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mapreduce.Test_project$TwoDArrayWritables
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:855)
    ... 10 more

16/04/05 15:48:34 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201604051120_0002_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mapreduce.Test_project$TwoDArrayWritables
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getMapOutputValueClass(JobConf.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.<init>(MapTask.java:966)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mapreduce.Test_project$TwoDArrayWritables
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:857)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:881)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mapreduce.Test_project$TwoDArrayWritables
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:855)
    ... 10 more
```

Googled many solutions but nothing worked. Please help!

Comment: can you provide the full command you are using to run the jar..

Comment: This is the command I used-                                                              bin/hadoop jar newproj.jar /user/hduser/input /user/hduser/output

Comment: try this maybe: bin/hadoop jar newproj.jar <fully qualified name of your class having the main()> /user/hduser/input /user/hduser/output

Comment: Syntax being: hadoop jar <jar> [mainClass]

Comment: there may a problem when you are exporting your executable `jar` there is a option during the process which Identify your Class which contains actual `main()` method.  have you select your class (Which contains main method ) During the exporting the` jar`  from the source-code ??

Comment: When we are adding the main class name then it is using the main class name as input path, and subsequently using the correct input path as output path, hence giving output path exists error.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap yes we did select the main class name, but it is still not working.

Comment: Is mapreduce.Test_project$TwoDArrayWritables on the classpath? Your class structure makes it appear like there's no mapreduce folder in your jar? Those classes would obviously need to be in the mapreduce folder in your jar.

Comment: @ ManoDestra  Yes its already inside the folder of mspreduce.

Answer (score 0):

try this:  `bin/hadoop jar /path/to/jarfile/newproj.jar Test_project.TwoDArrayWritables /user/hduser/input /user/hduser/output1`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please edit your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: While trying your proposed solution following is error is thrown- `INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://master:54310/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser/.staging/job_201604070951_0001
16/04/07 09:57:01 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://master:54310/user/hduser/input already exists
Output directory hdfs://master:54310/user/hduser/input already exists
`

Comment: @gariepy I guess it is not taking **Test_project.TwoDArrayWritables** as a class rather shifting everything for eaxample - Test_project.TwoDArrayWritables is taken as input and  /user/hduser/input as output directory and so on.

Comment: @Farheen Nilofer Please delete the output dir you are giving before you run the job or try with new o/p dir

Comment: @ Ashok, the ouput files are already deleted, it is taking input file as output, if we are adding one more argument of the class name.

Comment: @Farheen Nilofer Are you sure TwoDArrayWritables is your correct driver class and Test_project is your package name? you class name will be in the format packagename.driverclassname after the .jar path

Comment: package is `mapreduce` and driver class is `Test_project`

Comment: @Farheen Nilofer in that case command will be: bin/hadoop jar /path/to/jarfile/newproj.jar mapreduce.Test_project  /user/hduser/input  /user/hduser/output  be sure you have configured the job with map/reduce  classes in your driver class.

Answer (score 0):

Struggling for about weeks , something clicked in my mind i.e 
I was using two reducers in my job so defining two Jobconf for each:

My earlier(wrong code)

`JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), Test_project.class);
JobConf conf2 = new JobConf(getConf());`

As I thought that configuration is already defined so didn't mention class **Test_project.class** in **conf2**

My present (Correct Code)

`JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), Test_project.class);
JobConf conf2 = new JobConf(getConf(), Test_project.class);`

The error was thrown because on execution it was searching for Test_project$TwoDArrayWritables , as it has no Test_project.class class , it can not locate **TwoDArrayWritables**

Now it works fine.